# is there an issue in visiting a cemetery while menstruating?

Tags: halacha, niddah, evening-night, cemetery-grave

Is there an issue about going to a cemetery while menstruating?

If so, is it a prohibition or recommendation?

What about going to a cemetery at night?

I was told there might be an issue with this by several people, and I am asking if there is a basis or source for it.

Comment: The Vilna Gaon was opposed to ever visiting cemeteries. Personally, I've never heard of any distinction otherwise though I think as a general rule it doesn't seem the best idea to be going to isolated places at night.

Comment: @loewian visiting a loved one who is buried in a cemetery- on their yartzeit-did he oppose that?

Comment: He was opposed to that custom.

Comment: http://www.hakirah.org/Vol15Zuriel.pdf

Comment: Why do you suppose menstruation would be a relevant factor? In general, the nidah prohibitions are to prevent couples from being intimate during her nidah. I don't think visiting a cemetery would likely have a particularly aphrodisiac effect.

Comment: @Daniel I was told this by several people, I am asking if there is a basis or source for it. If you are unaware please refrain from weird responses.

Comment: @alicefine No one has provided a weird response as far as I can tell. I have incorporated your motivation for asking (which Daniel so effectively sought) into your question where it belongs, instead of in a comment. Please try to include your motivation for future questions from the outset.

Comment: @Daniel There are a number of things that it is (or was) minhag for women not to do while menstruating. Shul attendance in E"Y may be one. Baking challah in E"Y is definitely another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Pischei Tshuva in Yoreh Deah siman siff 195 #19 mentions a minhag not to go to the cemetery to pray during their Nida days.

See here starting by footnote 12 for some more information. http://shulchanaruchharav.com/Home-Database/default.aspx?pageid=women31

Comment: I come back to visit, and [6591 has a new user picture](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248140/266359). Classic!

Comment: @Shokhet I've been traveling over the Chag and each time a new one popped up I thought of you:)

Comment: @user6591 why? what is the connection? it is a place of tuma in the first place.....

Comment: @alice IIRC the explanation given is that it is a spooky tuma thing, not a halakhic tuma thing. The powers of tuma (kelipot) attach themselves to those more susceptible to them. A woman in the state of flowing or perhaps even just being tamei from nida acc to some opinions is extremely susceptible to the forces that reside in the cemetery. There is an extremely minority view that men who are tamei keri have this same susceptibility.

Comment: @Alice as an aside to the article linked, i noticed for the first time while double checking the Pischei Tshuva before writing, that the exact wording is to not go to pray. When it comes to spooky stuff, direct literal reading is the key. Therefore, to go for any other reason would be fine. I.e. for a burial, a yor tzeit, either of which is to honor the deceased. Also ok would be to go on tisha biav so as to remember where we all end up. The only thing prohibited would be to go specifically to pray.

Comment: Cont. So people who go on any random day to pray is a no no. Perhaps also disallowed is going during ten days of penance, as the point there is to pray. But CYLOR as this is a chidush that popped into my head.

Answer (score 0):

Rambam, Hilchos Aveilus 4:4 says that "Nor should one visit the cemetery".
Rav Yosef Karo, Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh Deah, Ch 359, says that women should not visit the cemetery (at all, under any circumstances).

Comment: But Rambam was opposed to practices that perpetuate non halakhic superstitions about niddot. Indeed, in his opinion one of the main points of the halakhot of nidda is to realign thinking on the topic away from these superstitions.